# Duplicate dynamically uploaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying duplicate dynamically uploaded images. I'm using drawImage() to do this. How do I use drawImage() to duplicate dynamically uploaded images while maintaining the aspect-ratio?

An example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uxj0v6u/1/)

html:

```
<button id="button1">Picture</button>
<div id="main">
    <img id="profile_pic" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/CocaColaBottle_background_free.png/200px-CocaColaBottle_background_free.png">
</div>
<div id="lgt_1">
    <div>
        <canvas id="lcv_1" class="drw"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    alert("sdfsfsdf")
    var ctx = $('#lcv_1').get(0).getContext('2d');
    var img = $('#profile_pic').get(0);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,75,75);
 });
```

If there are any other better ways of doing this, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Get the image size and paste it on the canvas using them. In your code you're using hard-coded sizes.

Comment: Do you want to keep the original image size, or scale it to the size of your canvas?

Comment: @MarcoCI: Thanks. Canvas has a fixed size. I'm looking to draw the image inside a canvas maintaing its aspect-ratio.

Comment: @imcg: Thanks. I want to scale the image to fit the canvas size while maintaining its aspect-ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have centered the image on canvas maintaining aspect ratio.
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uxj0v6u/5/).

```
 $("#button1").click(function(){
        //alert("sdfsfsdf")
        var ctx = $('#lcv_1').get(0).getContext('2d');
        var img = $('#profile_pic').get(0);
        var width = ctx.canvas.width;
        var height = ctx.canvas.width * (img.height / img.width);
        if (height > ctx.canvas.height) {
            height = ctx.canvas.height;
            width = ctx.canvas.height * (img.width / img.height);
        }
        ctx.drawImage(img,(ctx.canvas.width - width) / 2, (ctx.canvas.height - height) / 2, width, height);
  });
```

Comment: This seems to work. But if there are multiple canvas elements on the page will there be an issue when the word canvas is used? e.g.: `ctx.canvas.height` ? Should the `canvas` be referred by some variable name?

Comment: No issues with multiple canvas elements. Each context has a property canvas. No, the ~canvas~ should be left as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep height & width of image by:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
  alert("sdfsfsdf")
  var ctx = $('#lcv_1').get(0).getContext('2d');
  var img = $('#profile_pic').get(0);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width, img.height);
});
```

Comment: Only half of the image is drawn?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is calculate the scale needed to fit the image within the available area. This should work if the image is either too tall or wide.

It will also scale up smaller images to fit the area, so if that's something to you don't want, just limit the scale to 1.

```
var areaWidth = 300,
    areaHeight = 150;
var scale = Math.min(areaWidth / img.width, areaHeight / img.height);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
```

Edit: [Tested out on your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uxj0v6u/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Multiply your image width and height by the desired percentage:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    var ctx = $('#lcv_1').get(0).getContext('2d');
    var img = $('#profile_pic').get(0);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, img.width * 0.50, img.height * 0.50);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2uxj0v6u/3/

Comment: Thanks. That wouldn't work because as I mentioned the original image is dynamic. Can not have a fixed percentage.